# Is this aloe vera gel vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan, cosmetics

I use Fruit of the Wokali aloe vera gel, but I'm not sure whether it's vegan or not. Is Fruit of the Wokali aloe vera gel vegan?

Comment: What are the ingredients?

Comment: Please help make this question more answerable by including the ingredients if you know them!